# Zip or unzip a file with different file name encoding?

Tags: encoding, zip, unzip

I have files with name out-of-ASCII on a Linux server to zip. Unfortunately, UTF8-encoded files always have file name corrupted on extracting on Windows.

Is there a way to zip files with name encoded in a specific charset different to the local system charset? Or is there a tool that can extract UTF8-encoded files with correct name on Windows?

(If the solution is a script, PHP or Python are preferred.)

Comment: Good question, but belongs to super-user or such. This is a programming site.

Comment: The python solution is here https://gist.github.com/Xiao-Chong/b6bf1fc99fcfd2a1aa442588b049fb96

Answer (score 1):

Use 7z or 7zip.

Compress your files on Linux and decompress on Windows both by 7-zip.

Answer (score 1):

For python2 (filenames is russian) pls use cp866

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_handle, mode='w') as zip_file:
    for file_ in self._files.all():
        path = file_.file.path

        filename = u'Название файла.txt'
        try:
            filename = filename_utf.encode('cp866')
        except:
            ext = str(path.split('.')[-1])
            filename = '%s.%s' % (uuid4().hex, ext)

        zip_file.write(path, filename)
```

For python 3

```
file_handle = BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_handle, mode='w') as zip_file:
    for file_obj in files:
        zip_file.write(filename=file_obj.full_path, arcname=file_obj.file_name)
```

Comment: Please try to explain what you did to help others better understand your answer.

Comment: You are right, I will now describe the topic